# Terraform tries to load old defunct provider

Tags: postgresql, terraform, amazon-rds, hashicorp

Attempting to use cyrilgdn/postgresql provider but terraform continues to attempt to load hashicorp/postgresql, this causes init to fail. Currently using terraform 1.0.0, although the problems happens on 14.1 too - have not upgraded from 12.x, always run 14.1 or newer on this work.

I've reduced the code to the below, nothing else in this folder and still get the problem

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14.1"

  required_providers {
    postgres = {
      source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = ">=1.13.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "postgresql" {
  host = "TBC"
  port = 5432
  username = "TBC"
  password = "TBC"
}
```

init reports:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding cyrilgdn/postgresql versions matching ">= 1.13.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/postgresql...
- Installing cyrilgdn/postgresql v1.13.0...
- Installed cyrilgdn/postgresql v1.13.0 (self-signed, key ID 3918DD444A3876A6)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html
Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/postgresql: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a
provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/postgresql
```

terraform providers reports

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/postgresql]
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/cyrilgdn/postgresql] >= 1.13.0
```

How can I stop it trying to find hashicorp/postgresql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `postgresql`, not `postgres`:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14.1"

  required_providers {
    postgresql = {
      source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = ">=1.13.0"
    }
  }
}
```