# Terraform configure databases role for the azure Postgressql flexible server raising error

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have deployed Azure PostgresSQL Flexible server as a PAAS using terraform which is working fine . Now I want to create different Roles and assign different privilege's for the database using terraform. But it is raising the error which is mentioned bellow. Please have a look and suggests me the proper terraform configuration and required providers for the solution .

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/postgresql: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/postgresql
Did you intend to use cyrilgdn/postgresql? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/postgresql, run the following command:
terraform provider
```

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.6"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.20.0"
    }

    postgresql = { 
      source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = "1.15.0"
    }

  }
}

provider "postgresql" {
  host            = module.az_pssql_flex.azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server
  port            = 5432
  database        = var.databases_names
  username        = ""
  password        = ""
  sslmode         = "require"
  connect_timeout = 120
  superuser       = false

}
```

[image]

Comment: whats the output of `terraform providers`

Comment: ` Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/postgresql: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/postgresql
│ 
│ Did you intend to use cyrilgdn/postgresql? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/postgresql, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
`

Comment: `Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/plugins/signing.html`

Comment: sounds like somewhere in your config or modules you have listed the source of postgres without the namespace so its just defaulting to hashicorp

Comment: Can you please provide a example conf

Comment: Since you are using a non-official provider (i.e., postgresql) it was probably defined at the module level. You are referencing the module in your `postgresql` block. Check the module code and see if there are some `hashicorp/postgresql` module references and fix that.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190343/terraform-problem-to-define-cyrilgdn-postgresql-provider-properly

Comment: Thank you so much @Swarna  for the instruction . I  have created another "provider.tf" file in the child module(pssql mopdule) and define the pssql provider block  beside the root module porvider.tf file. Now it works.

Comment: posted the answer with same. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to create different Roles and assign different privileges for the database using terraform.

1. created an "provider.tf" file in the child module and define pssql module
   [image]
2. Define the postgresql provider block beside the root module porvider.tf file.
3. [image]
4. run terraform plan
5. run terraform apply.

Comment: Answers should include reelevant code in the body of the answer, not as a screenshot of text.